# Any javascript jquery plugin to select image from folder

Tags: php, jquery

I am using form ehere use has to type the image name like

```
images/pic1.jpg
```

Is there any way that user can graphically select the image and then the path automatically gets populated in that box

thanks

Comment: do you mean styling the <input type="file" control? or select an image hosted in your web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doubt that is achievable in JavaScript. You may want to use

```
<input type="file" class="file">
```

Read more on  here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

You can style it with CSS.

If JavaScript is able to do a gallery of some sort using your computer's images, it's quite a security flaw isn't it?

Comment: Actually its not actually i want to upload the image , i just want the automated way to enter the image path in that text box . Its a text box where i want to enter the image path

Comment: You mean to auto suggest a path?